# Wordpress IF Statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to remove certain part of the post if:

```
property-type&tag_ID=13
```

The content I'm trying to hide is:

```
<div class="single-property-meta clearfix status-<?php echo $status_id; ?>-text">
<?php
$meta_size = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_size', true );
**$meta_bedrooms = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_bedrooms', true );
$meta_bathrooms = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_bathrooms', true );
$meta_garages = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_garages', true );
$meta_address = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_address', true );**
?>
<span class="meta-size"><i class="ico-size"></i><?php echo $meta_size; ?></span>
**<span class="meta-bedroom"><i class="ico-bedroom"></i><?php echo $meta_bedrooms.'<span class="meta-hidden">'.__( ' Bedrooms' ).'</span>'; ?></span>
<span class="meta-bathroom"><i class="ico-bathroom"></i><?php echo $meta_bathrooms.'<span class="meta-hidden">'.__( ' Bathrooms').'</span>'; ?></span>
<span class="meta-garage"><i class="ico-garage"></i><?php echo $meta_garages.'<span class="meta-hidden">'.__( ' Garages').'</span>'; ?></span>**
<span class="meta-print visible-desktop"><i class="ico-print"></i><span class="print-hidden"><a href="javascript:window.print()"><?php echo __( 'Print this page'); ?></a></span></span>
<span class="meta-status"><?php echo $property_status; ?></span>
</div>
```

Any help would be welcome, I know I have to use some sort of a IF statement to show the content only IF the ID is = 13. All I have right now is this:

```
if ($property-type&tag_ID=13) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the part you wanna hide with:

```
<?if ($property-type && $tage_ID=13) {?>
    your hidden part
<?}?>
```

Actually Im not sure what `$property-type&tag_ID=13` is.

Comment: `$property_type`, `$property-type` is wrong. `$tage_ID=13` is assigning, not comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Very valid question. This is part of the reason I hate mixing HTML with PHP. It makes it all seem so complicated when it really is very simple.  So change these lines:

```
$meta_bedrooms = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_bedrooms', true );

<span class="meta-bedroom"><i class="ico-bedroom"></i><?php echo $meta_bedrooms.'<span class="meta-hidden">'.__( ' Bedrooms' ).'</span>'; ?></span>
```

To be these using pure PHP:

```
if ($property-type && $tag_ID != 13) {
  $meta_bedrooms = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'property_bedrooms', true );
}

<?php
if ($property-type && $tag_ID != 13) {
  echo '<span class="meta-bedroom">'
     . '<i class="ico-bedroom"></i>'
     . $meta_bedrooms
     . '<span class="meta-hidden">'
     . __( ' Bedrooms' )
     . '</span>'
     . '</span>'
    ;
}
?>
```

First note that your initial example `if` of `($property-type&tag_ID=13)` is wrong since `tag_ID=13` (note one `=`) is an assignment of a value. Also you have `tag_ID` set when it should be a variable like `$tag_ID`. So the final check as I have it is now `$tag_ID != 13` since you want to hide items if `$tag_ID` is `13`, which means you only want to show that content if `$tag_ID` is `13` so if `$tag_ID != 13` is set anything else will show the content, but if it is equal to `13` it is hidden.

That said, what is `$property-type` and what is the check there? The way I have it set it will be `TRUE` if there is any value set to `$property-type`, but perhaps that’s not needed and the conditional should simply be `if ($tag_ID != 13) {`.

That said, cleaning things up reveal other potential issues. Such as, what exactly is the purpose of this `<i class="ico-bedroom"></i>`? An `<i>` tag that closes itself right away? Your other `<span>` tags have similar `<i>` tags. Intentional?